# How to write scraped data to a data frame in the correct order in Python

Tags: python, selenium, dataframe, web-scraping

I have the following python program that is scraping through a website to get names, company name and addresses. This works fine. I am then trying to write the scraped data into a data frame. I want them in the correct order. Sometimes the website doesn't have the company name but only the name and address, is there any way I can specify that it takes a default value if the company name is not present? Because when I try to write it into a data frame I get this error:

"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index".

Because the company names are not present for each member.

```
memeberName = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.member-name')))
company = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.company-name')))
address = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.list-address-panel')))

mb = []
comp = []
add = []

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['MemberName', 'Company', 'Address'])

for getname in memeberName:
        print("Name:" + getname.text) #returns 20 results
        mb.append(getname.text)

for getcompany in company:
        print("CompanyName:" + getcompany.text) #returns 18 results
        comp.append(getcompany.text)

for getaddress in address:
        print("Address:" + getaddress.text) #returns 20 results
        add.append(getaddress.text)

df["MemberName"] = mb
df["Address"] = add
df["Company"] = comp

print(df)
```

The data that I need to scrape are inside div tags and it's not in a table. So I am trying to find a way to scrape the details in the correct order. I need the name, company and address of each one. If the company is missing for some I need to blank, NAN or null it should not take the company of a different name.

[image: Elements]

Comment: So the problem is not order, is to have an empty string to hold position? Modify how you extract data is the solution, if data is presented in table, iterate trs

Comment: Well, you can check...if company name is undefined/empty then pass the default value in the variable accordingly.

Comment: @Wonka please see my edit. The data are in div tags

Comment: @Sindu_ then iterate main div

Comment: @Wonka that would give me all the details together. But I have no way of identifying which one is the name, company name and address.

Comment: @Sindu_ then read how to ask a good question, I cant reproduce your problem with and image of html code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Below (using itertools.zip_longest)

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

mb = ['A','B','C']
comp = ['Z','X']
add = [12]


values = list(itertools.zip_longest(mb, comp, add))
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
print(df)
```

output

```
0  A     Z  12.0
1  B     X   NaN
2  C  None   NaN
```

Comment: Tried this but it does not come in the correct order

Comment: This is a bad answer, what happens if "A" dont have values and should have NaN/None value, your answer is only to asign value to lasts items